# image src attribut issue

Tags: asp.net, html, css, image

I am storing images in a folder on a localhost for asp.net website.

The image is there and and the src attribute is correctly formed but the image is not  displayed in img element.

can some body tell me what can be the issue or missing.. when I check the image in the url of brower it is displayed properly

```
     localhost:xxxx/TenModified/setX/8fd7976b-d4b0-467a-bc3e-bf2a51d60299.Jpeg
```

This is my markup for the element

```
<img id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolderChild_ListViewThumbs_ctrl1_ctl03_Image1" src="localhost:59657/ProfileTenModified/setP/8fd7976b-d4b0-467a-bc3e-bf2a51d60299.Jpeg" style="border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;height:172px;width:172px;" alt="">
```

Comment: Look at the network tab in the dev tools

Comment: what does your code look like?

Comment: try to use `.JPEG ` in `src`

Comment: What if you take the path and look it up in your browser? Is the Image displayed then?

Comment: Yes I mentioned in the question .. It does display ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use Prefix.  Http or Https

http:// localhost:xxxx/TenModified/setX/8fd7976b-d4b0-467a-bc3e-bf2a51d60299.Jpeg

```
<img src="http :// domain:port/TenModified/setX/8fd7976b-d4b0-467a-bc3e-bf2a51d60299.jpeg" />
```

Comment: the image element is generated by the <asp:image> element so I am not sure why this is generated malformed..

Comment: IF you dont write prefix to src. Browser will look 

http://yourdomain/path/domain:port/TenModified/setX/8fd7976b-d4b0-467a-bc3e-bf2a51d60299.jpeg
Browser thinks. IT's a directory under my site.

Comment: IF Image and your site in the same domain you can use @lucuma answer to fix your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to include the domain and port.  The following will work fine for the src:
`/ProfileTenModified/setP/8fd7976b-d4b0-467a-bc3e-bf2a51d60299.Jpeg`

or the full tag:

```
<img id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolderChild_ListViewThumbs_ctrl1_ctl03_Image1" src="/ProfileTenModified/setP/8fd7976b-d4b0-467a-bc3e-bf2a51d60299.Jpeg" style="border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;height:172px;width:172px;" alt="" />
```

Comment: both the http:// and /profileTenModified/ worked.. what is the explanation for this .. I am just curious..

Comment: The browser does not require the domain and port to reference assets in your project.  In fact, if you are hard coding (I hope not) you'll need to change it when you go into production to use the production URL.  Unless you have your assets on an external CDN, it is much easier to use these relative paths without the domain and port. In addition if you are using an SSL you won't need to make any changes.

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
src="ProfileTenModified/setP..."
```

full code:

```
<img id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolderChild_ListViewThumbs_ctrl1_ctl03_Image1" src="ProfileTenModified/setP/8fd7976b-d4b0-467a-bc3e-bf2a51d60299.Jpeg" style="border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;height:172px;width:172px;" alt="" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the "localhost:59657" from the path.  You really don't need it, just be root relative.  This will save you a lot of time when you launch your application not having "localhost:59657" in there and just being root relative.  You won't need to change all of your paths.  Same holds true for any anchors. Make those root relative too.

```
<img id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolderChild_ListViewThumbs_ctrl1_ctl03_Image1" src="/ProfileTenModified/setP/8fd7976b-d4b0-467a-bc3e-bf2a51d60299.Jpeg">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your link is is missing the two forward slashes in the protocol?

```
<img id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolderChild_ListViewThumbs_ctrl1_ctl03_Image1" src="localhost//:59657/ProfileTenModified/setP/8fd7976b-d4b0-467a-bc3e-bf2a51d60299.Jpeg" style="border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;height:172px;width:172px;" alt="" />
```

and also the slash for the closing of the image tag

Comment: for some reason the code did not display so i have added it below <img id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolderChild_ListViewThumbs_ctrl1_ctl03_Image1" src="localhost://59657/ProfileTenModified/setP/8fd7976b-d4b0-467a-bc3e-bf2a51d60299.Jpeg" style="border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;height:172px;width:172px;" alt="" />

Comment: The img mark up has been generated by asp.net's <asp:Image> element.. I am not sure the localhost address you specified